# Скрыть div при нажатии вне этого дива js

Tags: javascript, html

Подскажите пожалуйста, есть код:

```
$(document).ready( function() {
            $('#valuta').keyup(function(){
                if($(this).val().length > 0){
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url:"/autocomplete/auto_val.php",
                        dataType: 'json',
                        data: {'choose' : $(this).val()},
                        success: function(res){
                            console.log(res);
                            var content = '';
                            $.each(res, function(i, item){

                                content += "<div class='ott_v' data-id='"+res[i].id_v+"'>"+res[i].name_v+"</div>";
                                $("#vl").css({"margin-top": "29px", "background": "#fff", "position": "absolute", "margin-left": "138px", "width": "170px", "border": "2px dashed #e0e0e0", "text-align": "left", "padding": "5px", "font-size": "15px"});
                            });

                            $('.val').html('');
                            $('.val').append(content);
                        }

                    });
                }else{
                    $('.val').html('');
                }

            });

            $('body').on( 'click', '.ott_v', function(){

                var id = $(this).attr('data-id');
                $('.user_id').val(id);
                var txt = $(this).text();
                $('#valuta').val(txt);
                $('.val').html('');
$("#vl").css({"display": "none"});
            });

        } );
```

Который делает поиск и выводит в див информацию.
Этот див обертывается

`<span class='val' id='vl'></span>`

Как убрать класс vl если было нажатие ЛКМ вне этого span?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$(document).on('click', '.val', function() {
  $(this).addClass("red");
});

$(document).on('click', function(e) {
  if (!$(e.target).hasClass("val") && !$(e.target).closest(".val").length) {
    $(".val").removeClass("red");
  }
});
```

```css
.red {
  color: red;
}
.val {
  background-color:lightgreen;
  border:1px solid black;
  padding:5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class='val' id='vl'>The walrus and the carpenter ...</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Решение на нативном JavaScript:**

```js
var hideBlock = document.getElementById('block');
function menuCloseClickOutside(e) {
    if(!e.target.matches('#block')) {
        hideBlock.classList.remove('active');
    }
}
document.addEventListener('click', menuCloseClickOutside);
document.addEventListener('touchstart', menuCloseClickOutside);
```

```css
#block {
   display: none;
   background: yellow;
}
#block.active {
   display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div id="block" class="active">Блок, который будет скрыт.</div>
```